How to summarize counts by date and item as the column header with Pandas DataFrame
Given the following DataFrame in Pandas:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Date": [
            pd.Timestamp("2000-01-02"), 
            pd.Timestamp("2000-01-02"), 
            pd.Timestamp("2000-01-05"), 
            pd.Timestamp("2000-01-06"), 
            pd.Timestamp("2000-01-06"), 
            pd.Timestamp("2000-01-06") 
        ],
        "Item": ["A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "C"]
    }
)

which produces the following DataFrame:
    Date        Item
0   2000-01-02  A
1   2000-01-02  A
2   2000-01-05  B
3   2000-01-06  C
4   2000-01-06  C
5   2000-01-06  C

How do I summarize the data by Date with Item as column headers like the following format?
Date        A   B   C
2000-01-02  2   0   0
2000-01-05  0   1   0
2000-01-06  0   0   3

I tried
pivot_df = df.pivot_table(index='Date', columns='Item', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)

but that's giving me:
Item        A   B   C
Date            
2000-01-02  2   0   0
2000-01-05  0   1   0
2000-01-06  0   0   3

I don't want the "Item" in the column, just "Date A B C" as the columns.

You need to do two things:

reset the column index name (to remove Item)
reset the dataframe index (to make Date a column)

pivot_df.columns.name = ''
pivot_df = pivot_df.reset_index()

Output:
        Date  A  B  C
0 2000-01-02  2  0  0
1 2000-01-05  0  1  0
2 2000-01-06  0  0  3


pivot_df = pivot_df.reset_index()
pivot_df.columns = ['Date'] + pivot_df.columns[1:].tolist()

Output will be like below.
        Date  A  B  C
0 2000-01-02  2  0  0
1 2000-01-05  0  1  0
2 2000-01-06  0  0  3

